# Microsoft SQL Server - Conditional Variable Assignment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do something like this in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @isparent int;

SET @isparent = iif(account.parentid is not null,
                    1,
                    0);

SELECT
    IIF(@isparent = 1,
        parentenrollment,
        enrollment)            "Enrollment"
FROM
    Accounts
```

Obviously this is greatly simplified, but the idea is to store in a variable (@isparent, above) a value based on something from a table and then later re-read that variable, using it to determine what values to show.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I suppose that `account.parentid` is a typo and you mean `accounts.parentid`

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you don't need to the variable, I think you are trying to do as

```
SELECT
    IIF(parentid is not null,
        parentenrollment,
        enrollment) Enrollment
FROM
    Accounts
```

and it's the same as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ParentId IS NOT NULL THEN ParentEnrollment
            ELSE Enrollment
       END Enrollment
FROM Accounts
```

If you really want to check if `parentid` is null or not and store the value in a variable, then your query should return one (1) row, that can be done with two ways

- TOP and ORDER BY

  ```
  SELECT TOP 1 @isparent = IIF(parentid IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
  FROM Accounts
  ORDER BY <Your Order Here>
  ```
- WHERE clause with conditions that returns only 1 row

  ```
  SELECT @isparent = IIF(parentid IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
  FROM Accounts
  WHERE <Type Your Condition(s) Here>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
DECLARE @isparent int;

SELECT @isparent = IIF(parentid is not null, parentenrollment, enrollment)
FROM    Accounts
WHERE ... --  condition that returns single row
```